# How to add some data input in a CNN?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, autoencoders, pytorch, image-segmentation

There is this problem I have encountered, I was trying to classify the pixels from input image into classes, sort of like segmentation, using a encoder-decoder CNN. The “interested” pixels usually locate in the top right corner of the input image, but the input images are too big, which I have to slice them in patches, by doing this, each input patch loses its “which region of the whole picture it’s from” information.

I'm using pytorch, I thought of manually add this patch location info into the input, but then it will be convoluted, which does make sense to me since it's not a part of an image.

I'm new to this, not sure if I'm thinking the whole thing right, how should I manually add this info into the input correctly or if there is some keywords I can do some researches, in order to let the CNN taking position into account? Thank you.

Comment: Is your problem that the tiling scheme is losing positional information (where it is in the image) or losing contextual information (whats in the image that wasn't in the tile)?

Comment: @mshlis The first one, where it is in the image, sorry I didn't express it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your interest is positional information, encode it!

This could include learning an embedding for each position and leveraging that in your model. You could also use an approach to hard-encode rather than learn it (kinda like adding sinusoids in the transformer paper [Attention is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)

an example of a paper that encodes the 2D positional info: [Attention Augmented Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09925.pdf)